# systemd service not executing the script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script, sudo

My systemd service is as follows.

`/etc/systemd/system/caportal.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=@CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@

Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/home/pi/test2.sh

RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

/home/pi/test2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Hi this working........ > output
```

It is made executable by `sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/test2.sh`.
I have started the systemd service using `sudo systemctl start caportal`. It runs successfully.

output of `sudo systemctl status caportal`

```
● caportal.service - @CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/caportal.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-04-10 07:01:15 UTC; 1h 3min ago
  Process: 286 ExecStart=/home/pi/test2.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 286 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/caportal.service

Apr 10 07:01:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started @CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@.
```

Its showing that the service is working fine but the file `output` is not written with "Hi this working........ ".

But when we run `test2.sh` using command `sudo /home/pi/test2.sh', its working fine.

Why the script is not working when used with systemd service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is writing to a **relative path** called `output`.  A *relative path* does not begin with `/`; an *absolute path* begins with `/`.

The path is relative to the current working directory.  Since you did not define [`WorkingDirectory=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) and you're running the service as a system service, it defaults to the root directory `/`.  You should be able to find the file at `/output` (Current working directory `/` plus the relative path `output`).

If you are expecting the file to be written at a particular path, you should either specify an *absolute path* in your script or a `WorkingDirectory=` under `[Service]`.

Comment: Yeah.. the output is present in root directory